# Azure Auto Scale Up value - does it go over this value?

Tags: azure, scaling, azure-worker-roles

I have the following auto scale settings for a worker role. I'm scaling by queue sizes of *1000*.

[image]

if I set the *scale up by* value to *5* ... and I have go from 0 items in the queue to 2050 items ... what will azure do?

will it

1. create 5 instances (because it sees that i've got more than 1000 and scale in blocks of 5) .. and the realise *ru-roh. i've should only need 3* .. and it then slowly destroys 1 in 5 mins and another in 5 mins after?
2. Creates 3 VM's.

Next.. if i have 0 items in the queue and then suddenly gets 13,000 items in the queue, will it..

1. scale to 5. and each 5 mins after that add more (how many?) until required.
2. scale to 5. 5 mins later (queue is 12,600) scale to 10. 5 mins later (queue is 12,100) scale to 13.

etc.

just not sure how this scales up, by.

Comment: If you don't find answers to this and Azure's scaling doesn't work for you as you need to, check out AzureWatch @ https://www.paraleap.com - you'll be in full control of the scaling experience there